# Is UNION ALL based on a condtion is possible in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have two queries from two different set of tables. Like first will be Server role details and the other Database role details. I'm trying to Put that in a SSRS report such that at any point of time user should be able to select either

1. Single server role or all Server roles
2. Single Database role or all database roles
3. Both Server role and database roles at a time.

I have drop downs for Server roles and database roles with option to select multiple roles at a time.

I'm stuck with displaying both server roles and database roles at a time. If i do a UNION ALL of both queries I'll get both the server and database roles in a single report table. But not sure how to merge this requirement with my original report. Please help me with some suggestions.

Comment: add a hardcoded column  to each table that defines the source for each union.  (SQL Server vs datbase role) and users can filter on either both, or neither.  `Select 'SQL Server' as Src.... union all SELECT 'DB Role' as Src ... as myQuery`... then your query can use count(*) over partition by (role) etc to get counts for each if you need single or all etc.  ... if this isn't close then I guess I would need clarification on the question using sample data and expected results.

Comment: @xQbert Guess this would work for me! Let me try it! Thank you.

Comment: I would use a temp table with an extra field for **Server or Database** and add the data to the temp table IF it meets your parameter. This would be faster than always getting all the data.

Comment: Thank you for your Suggestion @Hannover Fist and Yes it did work faster.